# How to access the given json in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-cloud-functions

How can i access this json structure given below?

```
{
   "question":{
      "119380":{
         "email":{
            "-L8o-zzRRTOJQjI4BQZ0":"abc@gmail.com",
            "-L8odhdW2xAnayboUb8h":"abc@gmail.com",
            "-L8ouI_wt8hb_R0GvXZ5":"abc@gmail.com",
            "-L8p8b03ZpoKUQiYU_69":"abc@gmail.com"
         }
      },
      "123541":{
         "email":{
            "-L8whdSxfPa1DGXwtTuD":"abc@gmail.com"
         }
      },

   }
}
```

I am trying in the following way

```
 exports.sendspamalertNotification = functions.database
.ref("spam/question").onWrite(event => {
  const original = event.data.val();
  console.log(event.data.val());
```

Everything is printing in console but how can i access every question_id (numeric string) and email under that question_id (numeric string)?

Actually i m new to this so please sorry if its silly question !

Please provide some solution !

Comment: What have you tried? What isn't working

Comment: Actually i stucked because there is no name to access this numeric string, and this numeric string (basically a question_id) that will gonna change everytime! @Phil

Comment: and the numeric string will be unique every time for sure.

Comment: this json structure i have posted here is from console
i cant use it as you are showing in snippet.
@Mohammad Ali Rony

Comment: exports.sendNotification = functions.database
        .ref("leads/{push_Id}").onWrite(event => {
          const original = event.data.val();
          const email = event.data.val().email
          const location = event.data.val().location


this is the another example of a code which working fine.
in this way i need to access but there is no heading to access the numeric string?

Answer (score 1):

Use square brackets to access properties whose strings are invalid in dot notation:

```js
const someObj = {
  "question": {
    "119380": {
      "email": {
        "-L8o-zzRRTOJQjI4BQZ0": "abc@gmail.com",
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log(someObj.question[119380].email);
```

Comment: please vote to close such duplicate

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property '119380' of undefined
    at exports.sendspamalertNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite.event (/user_code/index.js:854:32)

    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:54:20

    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)

Above error is coming when i m trying this -


exports.sendspamalertNotification = functions.database
.ref("spam/question").onWrite(event => {
  const original = event.data.val();
  console.log(original.question[119380].email);
@CertainPerformance

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to access dynamic key JSON.

```js
var obj = JSON.parse('{"question" : {"119380" : {"email" : {"-L8o-zzRRTOJQjI4BQZ0" : "abc@gmail.com", "-L8odhdW2xAnayboUb8h" : "abc@gmail.com","-L8ouI_wt8hb_R0GvXZ5" : "abc@gmail.com","-L8p8b03ZpoKUQiYU_69" : "abc@gmail.com"}},"123541" : {"email" : {"-L8whdSxfPa1DGXwtTuD" : "abc@gmail.com"}}}}');
Object.keys(obj.question).forEach(function(questionKey){
    var question = obj.question[questionKey];
    console.dir(question);
    Object.keys(question.email).forEach(function(emailKey){
        var value = question.email[emailKey];
        console.dir( question.email[emailKey]);
    });
});
```